# to send value of <input> tag dynamically through iteration

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

this is my code:

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%
//String b1=request.getParameter("b1");
String fy=request.getParameter("fy1");
Connection con=conn.connectionprovider.getDbConnection();
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from institutemaster where fy='"+fy+"'");

out.println("<form action=adminlistvalidate method=post ><table border='3'>");
out.println("<tr><th>FINANCIAL YEAR</th><th>INSTITUTE ID</th><th>INSTITUTE NAME</th><th></th><th></th></tr>");



    **while (rs.next())
                    {%>
    <% out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getInt(2)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>active <input type=radio  checked=checked name="+rs.getInt(2)+" value=a /> </td><td>inactive<input type=radio name="+rs.getInt(2)+" value=b /></td></tr>"); %>**




<% }//request.setAttribute("name",rs.getInt(2));
           out.println("</table><input type=submit name=submit value=submit />");
           out.println("</form>");
             %>
```

now see the highlighted part. im sending each row of table obtained to next servlet page using dynamic name . i actually want to make an admin page in which admin can activate or deactivate intitutes at his will. so each active and inactive radio button has a name obtained from the database ie. a dynamic name.
 my next servlet page is:

```
try {


            Connection con=conn.connectionprovider.getDbConnection();
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from institutemaster");
            //out.println("tom");
          while(rs.next())
            {
              // out.print(" cat");


                **if( request.getParameter(rs.getInt(2)+"").equals("a") )
                {
                    int rs1=st.executeUpdate("update institutemaster set status='active' where instid="+rs.getInt(2)+"");
                    out.print("status=active");

                }
                else
                 {
                    int rs1=st.executeUpdate("update institutemaster set status='inactive' where instid="+rs.getInt(2)+"");
                         out.print("status=inactive");

                }**
            }
            //out.print("done");
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
```

now in this , i am able to recieve and compare only the 1st radio button value 
(see the highlighted area). it means that the only the first value through iteration is being sent from last page n other values are not.
any help please?

Comment: Because you need to add the values to the arraylist and send it your servlet and iterate them back here to get the list again